# (Updated) How to execute several lines of code in PowerShell from C?

Tags: c

**#Edited version with PowerShell example**

How do I execute several lines of code in PowerShell from C? I would prefer to use if the system() command from . Below is an example of a script that sends an email through Gmail, the script works fine by itself in PowerShell but not when used in the C program.

Here is the script:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   system("powershell.exe -w hidden -c"
          "$email = 'SENDER_EMAIL'"
          "$pass = 'SENDER_PASSWORD'"
          "$to = 'RECEIVER_EMAIL'"
          "$smtpServer = 'smtp.gmail.com'"
          "$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage"
          "$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)"
          "$smtp.EnableSsl = $true"
          "$msg.From = '$email'"
          "$msg.To.Add('$to')"
          "$msg.BodyEncoding = [system.Text.Encoding]::Unicode"
          "$msg.SubjectEncoding = [system.Text.Encoding]::Unicode"
          "$msg.IsBodyHTML = $true"
          "$msg.Subject = 'SUBJECT'"
          "$msg.Body = 'BODY_TEXT'"
          "$SMTP.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential('$email', '$pass');"
          "$smtp.Send($msg)");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you use `&&`?  e.g. `system("do_something && do_something);`

Comment: Yes, it's possible to use with one "&" however I want to be able to split the code into several lines for readability.

Comment: I don't have a PowerShell right here to test it but I suspect the problem is that your string literals get concatenated into `"powershell.exe -w hidden -cdo somethingdo somethingdo something"`. Try adding `\n` to the end of each string.

Comment: I have tried both "\r\n" and "\n" at the end of every line and neither work. I think that the problem is that each line executes one by one instead of at the same time.

Comment: Use the proposal by @FiddlingBits, with another detail `"powershell.exe -w hidden -c &&" \n
   "do something"`.

Comment: Can you use \ after each line?  For example: `"1 &&" \ "2 &&" \ etc.`

Comment: Nothing works, I start to think the problem is something else (however, the script works fine on itself). I added an example PowerShell-script that sends an email by Gmail so you all can see the problem. I hope it makes the problem a little more clear :)

Comment: What about putting this in a ps1 file and simply call this script passing parameters?